# How do I start a Docker container with new environmental variables WITHOUT overwriting existing environmental variables?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'd like to pass environment variables into a new container WITHOUT overwriting existing environmental variables. I've tried using `--env` but unfortunately it overwrites everything. I also can't set the variables after the container is already started - the software I'm using would get mad.

How can I send these variables in? I hope there's an option other than making a brand new image.

Thank you so much for your help

EDIT:

The image I'm launching already has preset environmental variables. Those preset environmental variables are overwritten when I run the following code:

`docker run --interactive --tty --rm --name $name --volume $mount --workdir $workdir -p $p --env DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 $image bash`

I want to set the environmental variable `DISPLAY=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0` when my container launches without overwriting the preset environmental variables.

Sorry I confused everyone. I hope this is clear now!

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? The passed in variable sets the environment variable if it is unset, otherwise does nothing?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating variables being unset when you don't expect it?

Comment: This isn't making sense to me. Environment variables are system-wide (more-or-less), so why do you want to override them AND not override them?

Comment: Your example should include the "preset environment variables" and desired variables inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new variable named DISPLAY2 in your app and set that to new variable. Leave DISPLAY set the old variable. this way your original variable in DISPLAY won't get overwrtiiten becuase you have not set it.

docker run --interactive --tty --rm --name $name --volume $mount --workdir $workdir -p $p --env DISPLAY2=docker.for.mac.host.internal:0 $image bash